# Reverse recovery body diode in synchronous buck converter

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, buck, switching-losses

I am building a synchronous buck converter from 72 V to 4.2 V 2 A. Is there a way to lower the losses of the lowside MOSFET’s body diode? I am using a switching frequency of 300 kHz and with the MOSFET I am using, the reverse recovery losses alone are coming to 1.84 W when using a MOSFET with a reverse recovery charge of 85 nC. Is there a way to minimize these losses? [This is the link to the MOSFET I am using.](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2004270935_onsemi-FDMC86260_C462733.pdf) Here's how I got 1.84 W: $$P = V_{\text{in}} \times Q_{\text{rr}} \times F_{\text{sw}} = 72 \times 85\text{ nC} \times 300\text{ kHz} = 1.84\text{ W}$$

Comment: You can try a Schottky in parallel with the body diode of the FET.  Layout would be important to be sure the parasitic inductance of the traces doesn't interfere with the Schottky turning on.

Comment: Are you sure that you are driving the sync MOSFET correctly. It sounds like you are not. The MOSFET itself should do the heavy lifting and 1.84 watts lost in the diode seems an awful lot.

Comment: @Andy aka I have not done any lab test. The 1.84W is from calculation. Is this usually the case? My idea is to reduce my switching frequency to about 50Khz. I know this will increase my LC component size. Are there any other disadvantages to lowering the frequency?

Comment: You should explain how you got 1.8 watts in your question.

Comment: @Andy aka I have put in the equation, p = Vin * Qrr * Fsw = 72 * 85nC * 300KHz = 1.84W

Comment: Do you understand that the sync MOSFET shorts out the body diode when it activates thus there is minimal dissipation in the body diode.

Comment: @Andy aka I am not aware. So this power loss is just instantaneous?

Comment: You need to study why we use a sync MOSFET and note that for a tiny fraction of time there will be some power dissipated in the bulk diode but, for most of the rest of the switching cycle, the MOSFET will short out that bulk diode.

Comment: @Andy aka noted. Thanks